# Retrieve value of selected element in the dropdown - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner in React and trying to understand binding and events. I have created a learning project and want to validate the dropdown on onChange. If no value is selected from the drop-down, then display an error message.

*Note: I'm using a custom library which has attributes for inValid and error with SelectField component. If inValid is set to true, it will trigger an error message.*

I've tried finding solutions on multiple sources and trying to resolve this since hours. Please have a look. Thanks in advance.

WeatherOptionsView.js

```
class WeatherOptionsView extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { reasonState: false, selectValue: null };
  }

  validateState(event) {
    if(!! event.target.selectValue ) {
      this.setState({reasonState: true});
    } 
  }

  render() {
    const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

    return (
      <ContentContainer fill>
        <Spacer marginTop="none" marginBottom="large+1" marginLeft="none" marginRight="none" paddingTop="large+2" paddingBottom="none" paddingLeft="large+2" paddingRight="large+2">
          <Fieldset legend="City">
            <Grid>
              <Grid.Row>
                <Grid.Column tiny={3}>
                    <SelectField selectId="city" required placeholder="Select" label={["City:"]} error={["Error message"]} onChange={this.validateState.bind(this)} isInvalid={this.state.reasonState} value={this.state.selectValue}>
                      <Select.Option value="City1" display="City1" />
                      <Select.Option value="City2" display="City2" />
                    </SelectField>
                </Grid.Column>
              </Grid.Row>
             </Grid>
        )}
        />
      </ContentContainer>
    );
  }
}

export default injectIntl(WeatherOptionsView);
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectValue' of undefined

Comment: There is nothing called selectValue in event.target. It is event.target.value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not in the binding but in your `validateState` implementation. You are expecting `event`, but the SelectField component is probably passing value. The value doesn't have the target attribute that you want. Try something like this, instead:

```
handleChange(value) {
    this.setState({selectValue: value, reasonState: !value});
}

// and then in the render: 

<SelectField onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>
    {/* ... */}
</SelectField>
```

Comment: When I try to print value of selectValue after setting the state, as console.log(this.state.selectValue), it shows null. So It's not setting the state correctly?

Comment: Got the answer. setState is asynchronous, so this.state will still contain the previous values.

Answer (score 1):

As it says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectValue' of undefined`, event.target value is undefined. Also you have to set `selectValue` in the local state onChange to send value prop for .

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [react.js](/questions/tagged/react.js)